# Why I can't display the variable on the textbox? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have textbox with instance_name `power`.

And I have variable called `laserpower` as `int = 100`.

I wanted to display the `laserpower` on `power` textbox.

I have used this, but it doesn't work.

```
var laserpower:int = 100;

.....

function onFrame(e:Event): void {
    power.text = String(laserpower);

....
}
```

is there another way that I can make it?

Comment: I assume you've tried just putting a value in place of String(laser power); such as "hello world". What effect does that have?

Comment: You should be able to pass int values to a text field. So even just power.text = laserpower; should work. Try both those things and let us know what happens.

Comment: I assume that your textbox (Textfield or TextArea or ???) is placed on the stage. So you have to declare a variable that points to your "power" item.
var testText:Textfield = power; Then try assign the value like this :  testText.text = laserpower.toString();
did you check your onFrame function by just test the values by simply using trace() ?
trace(laserpower); trace(e.target); and trace(power); if trace(power) outputs null, undefined or throw an Error, this is a linkage problem.

Comment: @tatactic Please don't propose edits to the question as a way of answering the question.  That's what the answer box is for.

Comment: "it doesn't work" How doesn't it work?  Do you get an error message, or does nothing happen?  Where is `power` defined?  Do you have a document class, or is this all on the timeline?

Comment: I have try `power.text = laserpower` but I get error "implicit coercion of value of type int to an unrealated type String"

Comment: `trace(laserpower)` works on me. "It doesn't work" means I get "00" value on my textbox. `power` defined on timeline.

Comment: @Brian sorry, I found this workaround to suggest something.
As it was not an answer i though it was the better solution to do this.
I'll remember this rule in the future.
Thank you.

Comment: Try power.text = laserpower.toString();

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem, the textField displays "100"...

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;

var laserpower:int = 100;
var power:TextField = power;
var debug:Boolean = false;

function onFrame(e:Event): void {
    // trace the values one time only.
    if(!debug){
        trace ("event type = " + e.type);
        trace ("power = " + power + " laserpower = " + laserpower);
        debug = true;
        // outputs:
        // event type = enterFrame
        // power = [object TextField] laserpower = 100
    }

    power.text = laserpower.toString();
}

this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onFrame);
```

Tell us more about the code (on the timeline, on a separate class file?).

Where did you add the "addEventListener" method and what kind of Event do you're listening for?

What's the output if you add the trace() code?